# How to move div to another div on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to move a div(called panel) to the bottom under another div. but when i move the panel under the div(panel_1), there is no space under the page anymore. I want to move the div(panel) much further beneath . i should be able to scroll to get to the div(panel).

How do i achieve this?

PS: sorry for my english

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .panel {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel_1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the height of the page if not it is set to be enough to contain all of ur elements

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) { /* adjust to your needs */
  .panel {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
  }
}


.body{height 1000px;}
 .panel {
    background: red;
    height:10px;
  }
  .panel_1{background: blue;
  height:10px;}
```

```html
  <div class="panel">

    </div>

    <div class="panel_1">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have CSS properties which is **margin** to create space around 
each side of your target element.

Hope this will help you :)

try below snippet.

```html
<div id="panel1" style="border:solid;width:150px;height:150px;">
</div>
<div id="panel2" style="border:solid;width:150px;height:90px;margin-top:1%;">
</div>
```